# How to display a variable in Django forms?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I am trying to use the value of my database to display it in the form. So if a user already filled a value before, they will see it when they access again to the page.

So there is my HTML file :

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-4 mt-1 text-right">Modèle</label>
    <div class="col-4">
      {{ form.model }}
    </div>
</div>
```

My views.py file :

```
def get_car(request, identifiant):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CarForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            car_instance = Car(
                identifiant,
                form.cleaned_data["model"]
            )
            car_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/forms/car/{}".format(identifiant))
    else:
        form = CarForm()
        form.identifiant = identifiant
    return render(request, "forms/car.html", {"form": form})
```

My models.py file :

```
class Car(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

(primary key is automatically created)

And my forms.py file :

```
class CarForm(forms.Form):
    model = forms.CharField(label="Modèle", max_length=32, widget=forms.TextInput({ "value": Car.objects.get(pk=1).model}))
```

We can see in the forms file that I gave a value to pk, so the code will search the value from the user whose pk = 1 in my database. My question is how to give the pk value from the active user ?

Comment: Is there a log in system? And is the car model related to the user in any way?

Comment: No there is no log. And the car model isnt related for now to the user model but it will

Comment: `My question is how to give the pk value from the active user ?` → you may use `request.user.email` inside `get_car` function to get `email` and insert it into form https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test . If `request.user` is `None` or something like this, that mean the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `form = CarForm()` you create an empty form instance. No wonder the form shows up empty.
I would seriously recommend you to switch to class-based views (UpdateView and CreateView) as they created exactly for this type of usage and are super easy to implement.

Anyway, all you need to do here is to generate the form instance with the object that you plan to update.

I'm gonna guess that `identifiant` is a car ID(?)

```
car = Car.objects.get(id=identifiant)
form = CarForm(instance=car)
```

I would also suggest you to use a ModelForm instead of a standard form for your Car since you are collecting just the single field "model" in the "Car" model.

```
class CarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['model']
        widgets = {
            'model' : forms.TextInput(),
        }
        labels = {
            'model' : 'Modèle'
        }
```

You can add other attributes this way. You can add anything you want from there really. For example:

```
class CarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['model']
        widgets = {
            'model' : forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': '12345678',
                'class' : 'shadow-sm',
                'onClick' : "myFunction(this);"
            }),
        }
        labels = {
            'model' : 'Modèle'
        }
```

Anything you put there will be rendered in the field. So if you add css classes you can put them all in the same line. For example
`'class' : 'shadow-sm mx-3 bold-p text-responsive'`