# Display a variable in a Django form

Tags: django

I am trying to display a value from the database to a form. So if a user filled his email address, when he is connected he will see it in the email address form. I already did a post about this but I didn't get a lot of answer so I won't show my code this time but just ask you : Do you have an example of how to do it please ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/#variables

Comment: I know how tu use a variable in Django. I am talking about the specific case of using a variable to set a value to a form.

Comment: could you share your models, views and forms file

Comment: Well as I said in the post, I already posted my code in another post but I didn't get much answer. But if you really want to see it, here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68390098/how-to-display-a-variable-in-django-forms?noredirect=1#comment120867210_68390098

Answer (score 0):

If someone need the answer to this question, check this post : [How to display a variable in Django forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68390098/how-to-display-a-variable-in-django-forms?noredirect=1#comment121035934_68390098)

Now, stackoverflow bot think this should be a comment and not an answer so im just gonna paste some random code so he will leave me alone.

```
x = 1
if x == 1:
    # indented four spaces
    print("x is 1.")
```